# what is the best of showing a NSDictionary of NSArrays?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, tree, nsdictionary, nstreecontroller

I have a `NSDictionary` that each key refers to an `NSArray` object, I want to show the contents on a Cocoa APP on mac OSX 10.5, What is the best solution to this?

Maybe `NSTreecontroller`?

Comment: That all depends on what the information is, and how your customers might want to see that information presented really.

Comment: well, Key is website URL AND it refers to a NSArray that contains the URLs of that website.

Comment: The point is, you should display the data that you think should be displayed.  There is no "magic" way for the system to look at an NSDictionary and know what you want done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kinds of tree structures are well displayed by components like [`NSOutlineView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [`NSBrowser`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBrowser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Please also have a look to [Outline view programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OutlineView/OutlineView.html) by Apple, which introduces the subject (at least for outline views).

Comment: Thanks, I think NSOutlineView is what i need :)